# How can I store dataset() in Application variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dataset, application-state

Is it possible to create an Application State which can store DataSet()?
I want to create DataSet variable that may be available for any user. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to give a adataset to user?

Comment: I want every user who logs in to be added to the public table, which will contain his IP address, his username and the time he logged in. *I don't want to use database for this - I want to use an Application State variable *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of setting

```
 if(Application["myGlobalDataset"] == null)
     Application["myGlobalDataset"] = LoadMyDataSet();
```

However, read carefully the MSDN (bold is mine)

> Application state is a data repository that is available to all
> classes in an ASP.NET application. Application state is stored in
> memory on the server and is faster than storing and retrieving
> information in a database. Unlike session state, which is specific to
> a single user session, application state applies to all users and
> sessions. Therefore, application state is a **useful place to store
> small amounts of often-used data that does not change from one user to
> another**.

A good place to initialize the variable is in the `Application_Start` event found in the `global.asax.cs` file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if(Application["myGlobalDataset"] == null)
        Application["myGlobalDataset"] = LoadMyDataSet();
}
```

and remember to destroy it in the `Application_End` event

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown
     if(Application["myGlobalDataset"] != null)
        Application["myGlobalDataset"].Dispose();
}
```

If you plan to modify the content of the Dataset keep in mind that you need to prevent concurrent access to the variable and thus a locking mechanism is required.

```
 try
 {
     Application.Lock()
     Dataset ds = Application["myGlobalDataset"] as Dataset;
      ......
  }
  finally
  {
      Application.UnLock()
  }
```

The Lock persists until the page terminates processing or times out, however I still prefer to enclose everything in a try/finally block

Comment: And now in order to add a new row to the the table I just need to consider the Application variable as a DataSet variable?

Comment: Now if you plan to modify this dataset then other problem arises like concurrent access to the same variable.

Comment: I can't find the global.asax file. How do I create one?

Comment: Right click on Solution explorer and select Add New item, then add the Global Application Class item

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to store the DataSet in an application variable?

```
Application["YourDataSet"] = YourDataSetVariable.
```

From your other comments it is probably best to store it in a Session variable since it seems you are going to keep updating the information.